# Method Overloading in PHP

Tags: php, methods, overloading

Excuse my newbishness. While working on an ASP.Net based website, I remember seeing some methods in which could accept a different number of arguments. Specifically, they would do different things, depending on the number of parameters passed to them.

For example:

```
Email.sendEmail(address,subject,body);
```

would do something different to:

```
Email.sendEmail(address,bccaddresses,subject,body);
```

Is it possible for methods in PHP to do something similar? What is this thing called? Or have I just totally misremembered something?

Comment: This is called [method/function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). PHP does not have this natively without hacky workarounds involving func_get_args or confusing variable names. Boo :-(

Comment: @cbuckley PHP seems to have an even better way of overloading  . . . http://stackoverflow.com/a/9332030/798818

Comment: Overloading != optional parameters. This allows for different arity but checking of data types must be handled in the function rather than explicitly defining multiple function signatures.

Comment: @cbuckley That's it! I thought it was called "overloading", but I couldn't find a good example of it, for some reason.

Comment: Ah, well. I guess it's not supported in PHP :( If you want to put it in an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: See my new answer about using assoc arrays.  It's not perfect but it lets you take advantage of named arguments so that you can make some optional.  Lots of php frameworks make heavy use of this type of function.

Comment: I would agree with Tim on this one, as it also allows for extensibility without breaking E_STRICT compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an associative array as the argument, and make use of [extract()](http://php.net/extract).

```
function sendMail($opts){
    extract($opts, EXTR_SKIP); // EXTR_SKIP prevents extract from overwriting anything already in the symbol table
    if(isset($bccaddresses)){
        // do something with the bcc addresses
    }
    echo "sending some mail to $to with subject $subject";
}

sendMail(array("to"=>"test@test.com", "subject"=>"Hi!"));
```

This lets you pass in the arguments as named values, with optional values as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

```
function sendEmail($address, $bccaddresses, $subject, $body=NULL) {
  if ($body === NULL) {
     $bccaddresses=""; //or whatever default you want
     //shift arguments:
     $subject = $bccaddresses; $body = $subject;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 This was what I was referring to as confusing variable names :-) Works well but can be hellish without good documentation!

Comment: +1 This does look like it could work, but I'll go with your recommendation, cbuckley.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for **[`func_num_args()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)** and **[`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)**.

See also related examples, it shows you how to do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you set default values for functions.

```
function myFunc($val1 = 1, $val2 = 2, $val3 = 3){
    echo "$val1 $val2 $val3";
}


myFunc();     // outputs 1 2 3
myFunc(5);    // outputs 5 2 3
myFunc(8, 1); // outputs 8 1 3
```